# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type [(Int, Int)] with actual type IO [(Int,Int)]

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, when I doing the exercise, I have a function to get random pairs from[-10,10]:

```
randomList :: IO [Int]
randomList = randomRs (-10, 10) `fmap` newStdGen

pairs :: IO [(Int, Int)]
pairs = liftM2 zip randomList randomList

getNPairs n = take n `fmap` pairs

<Main>  getNPairs 3 
[(-6,3),(2,3),(1,-2)]
```

And I have also defined several new types:

```
data Point x y= Point Int Int  deriving (Show)
data Bool3 = True3 | False3 | Unk3 deriving (Show)
data Maybe3 a= Just3 a | Unknown3 | Missing3 deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

How could I get a Maybe3 (Point) list which put the getNpair value to Point.
Such as if I could get pair like `[(-6,3),(2,3),(1,-2)]` then I get

```
Just3 Point -6 3, Just3 Point 2 3, Just3 Point 1 -2
```

How to change the type here.
Now I write a function maybePoint:

```
getPoint (x,y) = Just3 (Point x y)
maybePoint n= map getPoint (getNPairs n)
```

But is shows : `Couldn't match expected type [(Int, Int)] with actual type IO [(Int,Int)]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any ideas how to approach this? You can't "escape" the `IO` monad so anything you do will eventually end up back in `IO`. As a suggestion, write a function `(Int, Int) -> Maybe3 Point` and go from there

Comment: My first thought is try to write the Point into the IO process, but I don't know how to do it. Let me consider about your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect `data Point x y = Point Int Int` to be good for? Either make it `Point = Point Int Int`, or `Point coord = Point coord coord` (so the coordinate type can also be e.g. `Double` when you wish so), or _possibly_ `Point x y = Point x y` (to allow both coordinates to have _different_ types – though that wouldn't seem a very useful idea to me). Perhaps the best thing would be a simple type synomym, i.e. `type Point = (Int,Int)`.

Comment: @jozefg Hi, what do you mean about `(Int, Int) -> Maybe3 Point` , is it a type or something?

Comment: @Xie Yes. Writing a function to transform a tuple into a `Maybe3 Point` + some plumbing with `mapM` and you should be good.

Comment: @jozefg Ye, it's easy to transform a tuple into `Maybe3 Point` , but I still don't know how to deal the `IO[(Int,Int)]`, I've tried this        `getPoint (x,y) = Just3 (Point x y)   maybePoint n = mapM getPoint getNPairs n`

Comment: I think you've forgotten the parens around `getNPairs n`

Comment: @jozefg oh, I forgot to type $ there. But I think it didn't work because the `(Int Int)` and `IO [(Int Int)]`

Comment: @jozefg I can appreciate trying to help a beginner, but I think it's a stretch to say you "can't escape the `IO` monad". You can't *safely* escape the `IO` monad, but there are cases where it is the appropriate thing to do. Granted, this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @Eric I almost always ignore Haskell's "warty" parts, `undefined`, `unsafePerformIO`, `unsafeInterleaveIO` because they're almost all more trouble than their worth.

Comment: So can I achieve the maybePoint there? Because I have tried several times, it still didn't work.

Comment: If you are just generating random lists for test purposes, consider using a test library like quickcheck or hunit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to work it out in `do` notation.

`getNPairs n` has type `IO [(Int,Int)]`, so to get at the list of pairs we need to use `<-`:

```
do ps <- getNPairs n             -- ps has type [(Int,Int)]
   ...
```

Now that we have a list, we can map it with `getPoint`:

```
   ...
   let points = map getPoint ps  -- points has type [Just3 Point]
   ...
```

But we're still in the IO monad, so we have use `return` to convert this pure value into a monadic one:

```
   ...
   return points
```

This `do` block has type `IO [ Just3 Point ]`.

Comment: Hi, I also thought about do block before, it should be sample. But when I tried like your suggestion, it didn't pass the compile.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know how to deal with this kind of problem.